# Integrating Sparrowhub with Atlassian bamboo

Tags: maven-3, artifactory, bamboo, sparrow-framework, bamboo-artifacts

We are in process of setting-up automatic deployment for our application. Our servers are hosted in a cloud environment. Currently, we are doing manual deployment and uploading artifacts in SparrowHub artifactory. We want to integrate sparrowhub with Atlassian bamboo to automatically upload the artifacts.

"Artifactory Generic Deploy" plugin of Bamboo only allows artifact to upload in JFrog artifactory but our artifacts are available in sparrowhub. We are not able to find anything on integrating sparrowhub with bamboo. Please provide inputs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you have a slight mixup of terms.
[Atrifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/) is a universal artifact repository manager made by JFrog.
it has a Bamboo plugin.

[SparrowHub](https://sparrowhub.org/) is a different product. it us a repository of sparrow plugins.

HTH,